# Theme Templates

Tags: theming

I don't have extensive knowledge of Drupal so I'm hoping I can get this question answered. Is it possible to coerce Drupal into loading a template based on a portion of a URL? For example, if a URL were constructed as http://example.com/cities/ where  could be the name of any state. Is it possible to get Drupal to load a 'cities' template and ignore the name of the state? The template would deal with the name of the state and populate the page from a database that Drupal was not aware of.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Drupal's template suggestions: https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question depends on whether you are using nodes, or want to create a custom output for your page.

If it is a custom output, then your steps will be as follows:

1. implement hook_menu to register your new path
2. register a theme function (backed by a template) that will populate your page.
3. create the template that will print the html and data to your page
4. In your module's callback function, you read the data from your custom database, then populate a render array that takes as '#theme' key your newly registered theme, passing in the variables you read in from the database as additional theme params. You then return that render array. Optionally, you can just call theme() on your registered theme and return the resultant string.

API docs to look at:

1. [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)
2. [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I've been looking for. I have 547 different topics and the page to display each topic contains up to four different elements. Each page is constructed in the same way. I didn't want to have to create (or register) the content of 547 different pages just to be able to display them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are trying to load cities in a template from a database. This isn't what templates are meant for and will even be impossible in Drupal 8.

Getting data should be done by modules. Only the layout (html, css, ...) should be in the templates.

I think the easiest way to do what you need is creating a taxonomy vocabulary 'States' (https://www.drupal.org/node/23405). Then create a content type 'Cities'(https://www.drupal.org/node/774728). Add a term reference field to your content type and be sure to select 'States' as vocabulary. Now you can create cities and 'tag' them with a state. Drupal will automatically make a page for every state with all the tagged cities.